# python writing output to csv file

Tags: python

hi i am trying to put the message which method check() call and writing to CSV file, however that is an error saying "iterable expected, not NoneType",wasn't sure my way is logical or not, can anyone here help me out?

```py
import json
import datetime
import time
import csv

t=45
h=50
d = datetime.datetime.now()
e = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

def check():

 # check the temperatur and humidy in range or not
 with open('config.json') as myfile:

  data=json.load(myfile)

  if data["min_temperature"] <= t <= data["max_temperature"] and data["min_humidity"] <= h <= ["max_humidity"]:
   print(e,"OK")

  elif data["min_temperature"] > t or t > data["max_temperature"] : 
    print (e," BAD   Temperature is detected out of config range.")

  elif data["min_humidity"] > h or h > ["max_humidity"]:
     print (e,"BAD   Humidity is deteced out of range.") 
  else :
     print("Error")


result=check()

with open('report.csv', 'wb') as myfile2:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(result)
```

Comment: your check() method doesn't return anything. Therefore result would be NoneType. What do you intend to have in the result

Comment: @RanikaNisal for the check method every time it runs it will show the print message(for example, DateTime and"error"), i want to put that message into the csv file

Comment: @PaulRooney the error is excatly what belowing comment points out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is what you need simply add

```
def check():

# check the temperatur and humidy in range or not
    with open('config.json') as myfile:

    data=json.load(myfile)

    if data["min_temperature"] <= t <= data["max_temperature"] and data["min_humidity"] <= h <= ["max_humidity"]:
        return ','.join([e,"OK"])

    elif data["min_temperature"] > t or t > data["max_temperature"] : 
        return ','.join([e," BAD   Temperature is detected out of config range."])

    elif data["min_humidity"] > h or h > ["max_humidity"]:
        return ','.join([e,"BAD   Humidity is deteced out of range."]) 
    else :
        return "Error" //or Print Error depending on what you want
```

additionally, you want to open your file in appending mode "a" instead of "wb"

Change it into

```
with open('report.csv', 'a') as myfile2:
     myfile2.write(result+'\n')
```

or keeping that part of the code the same. Simply turn all the return statements to this format

```
return [e,'msg']
```

Comment: Thanks !!!! that works but however, the CSV file shows the message into every single column like 2019 is [2][0][1][9]...etc how can merge it into one column?

Comment: Oh sorry was focused more on the check() function than the actual writer. In your writers case will make the edit

Comment: yeah wasnt sure how to make the edit , i hv try for val in report and writerow ([val]) but it doesnt work

Comment: regardless of what method you use the file must be open in 'a' mode not in 'wb'. 'wb' implies writing in binary mode which will give you an error since you are writing strings

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to return anything in your function `check`. Here is a little contrived example that might be easier for you to see what is going on.

```
>>> def say_hello(name):
        print('Hello {}!'.format(name))
>>> say_hello('John Doe')
Hello John Doe!
>>> greeting = say_hello('John Doe')
Hello John Doe!
>>> greeting

>>> greeting is None
True
```

In Python, if a function does not have a return value, it defaults to `None`. Which is the expected behavior! Though this is not very intuitive when you are first learning!